# Finding the coefficient of $x^n $ in a rational expression

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, binomial-coefficients

For a homework question, I need to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\frac{-x^7}{4(1-x)^2}$.

I've never done anything like this, and my teacher said he will take it up in tomorrow class, but I'm really curious as to how I can do this.

I know that I need to use the negative binomial expression, but I'm not sure how to deal with the $x^7$ term in the numerator.

Any help to get me started would be great. Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that answers can be marked as accepted?

Comment: The $x^7$ factor will simply shift the exponents in the binomial expansion by $7$.

Answer (score 2):

Coefficient of $x^{n}$ in $\frac 1 4 (-x^{7}) (1+x+x^{2}+\cdots)(1+x+x^{2}+\cdots)$ is $-\frac 1 4(1+1+\cdots+1)$ where there are $(n-7+1)$ one's. So the answer is $-\frac 1 4 (n-7+1)$for $n \geq 7$. It is $0$ for $n <7$.

Comment: Did you mean $(n-7\color{red}{+1)}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$(1-x)^{-2}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n
$,
$x^m(1-x)^{-2}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^{n+m}
=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} (n-m+1)x^{n}
$,
so the coefficient of
$x^n$ is
$n-m+1$.

For $m=7$ this is
$n-7+1 = n-6$.

Since your divides this by
$-4$,
the answer is
$-(n-6)/4$.